# Shutting down Redis

Tags: redis

I started up Redis for the first time on my local machine today and then later closed all terminal windows after I shutdown my Rails app. An hour later, I started up the Rails app again and did the following to start the redis server

```
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

However, it told me

```
# Opening port 6379: bind: Address already in use
```

I therefore assumed it was still running its earlier instance even though I closed the terminal windows on my Mac.

Looking at this page http://redis.io/commands/shutdown, I tried to run

```
SHUTDOWN
```

in the terminal window but I get this response

```
SHUTDOWN: NOT super-user
```

I therefore tried (Even though I didn't use sudo to start it)

```
sudo SHUTDOWN
```

and after it asked me for my password, it output this

```
usage: shutdown [-] [-h [-u] [-n] | -r [-n] | -s | -k] time [warning-message ...]
```

but when I randomly ran `shutdown -s` it said

```
 SHUTDOWN: NOT super-user
```

What's the proper way to shutdown Redis when I close up my app?

Comment: Hey, I accidentally downvoted your question 15 minutes ago. I've just realized that but I can't undo it. If you edit it I think I can undo it. I'm really, really sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is meant to be sent as a command to redis, not to be executed on your terminal.

In this case you can actually just `kill` redis from the terminal, since upon receiving a `SIGTERM` signal it will schedule a SHUTDOWN instead of simply exiting.

For reference [see the signal handling doc page.](http://redis.io/topics/signals)

Comment: actually, running 'kill' gives me this kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

Comment: You need to provide the Process ID to kill, so it knows where to send the SIGTERM signal. Take a look at this: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?kill

Comment: ok, for anyone looking at this answer, I got the process id by doing 'redis-cli info | grep process_id' and then ran 'kill 2694'

Comment: "ps aux | grep redis" is the normal way, fyi :)

Comment: how to tell ps to include column headers ?

Answer (score 37):

Use the built-in redis client: `redis-cli shutdown`

Comment: Should be the top answer.

Answer (score 3):

Find out the process id of the Redis instance running on your machine...

```
> ps aux | grep redis

impadmin 23277  0.0  0.0  35044  1976 pts/2    Sl+  14:19   0:00 src/redis-server
```

... and then run:

```
> kill 23277
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but kept noticing that my `redis-server` process kept changing its PID for some reason... So each time I ran `ps aux | grep redis` the displayed PID would be different from the previous run of `ps aux | grep redis`. Ultimately `redis-cli shutdown` was what I wanted.