# How do you shutdown Redis on Mac OS X?

Tags: redis

Just exactly how *do* you shutdown Redis on a Mac OS X server?

I tried doing it via the CLI but this doesn't work:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> shutdown
not connected> quit
```

I also tried executing the redis-cli command using "sudo" but that didn't make a difference.

I tried killing the process but it just restarts itself with a new PID:

```
$ sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

I've checked the "requirepass" setting in /usr/local/etc/redis.conf but no password is being set.

I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138872/shuting-down-redis), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088053/stop-redis-server-neither-shutdown-nor-stop-works), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088053/stop-redis-server-neither-shutdown-nor-stop-works) but none of them yielded a solution.  You'd think the Redis documentation would tell how to do this.  Very frustrating.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shuting down Redis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138872/shuting-down-redis)

Comment: Try to uninstall Redis from Mac OS X. This link will help you:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130310/uninstall-redis-on-mac-osx-older-version-is-running-after-installing-update)

Answer (score 4):

Just had this issue. I forgot I had installed it with brew and had set it up to be on by default so I was shutting it down but it just came back. `brew services stop redis`

Answer (score 1):

Its already working when you give the command the "shutdown". Its showing not connected just after that. You can verify the same by

```
ps aux | grep redis-server
```

Comment: That's not correct.  I can still see the process running.

Comment: @Jim You need to grab it's process id (4 or 5 digit)/ usually on second column from result above and hit next command `kill -9 1234`