# Uninstall Redis on Mac OSX. Older version is running after installing update

Tags: macos, redis, homebrew

**On a mac, how to I find the older version of Redis and uninstall it completely?**

I'm using OSX and installed Redis using the following command `brew install redis`. The version installed by brew states `redis-3.0.7`.

However, when I run the command: `redis-server` the output states it's I'm running `Redis 2.6.9 (00000000/0) 64 bit`. I have no idea where this version was installed from.

I have tried to download redis directly and use `sudo make uninstall` but got get this error:

```
cd src && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make uninstall
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.
make: *** [uninstall] Error 2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Checkout these directories:

```
ls -al $(which redis-server)
ls -al $(which redis-cli)
```

If these binaries were installed through `make install` from Redis source code you can simply remove them.

Answer (score 6):

Delete Redis folders using the following command

```
rm /usr/local/bin/redis-*
```